# Link from HTML text (nested in shinyServer) to specific Shiny tabPanel (in shinyUI)

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for a way to link from an HTML text (nested in the server part) to a specific Shiny tabPanel (nested in UI). Let's say we have the following app:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type="tabs",
        tabPanel("Contents", htmlOutput("contents")),
        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")) # <- A link to here
      )
    )
  )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderText({
    HTML("A link to <a href='#Plot'>Plot</a>") # <- from there
  })

  output$plot({
    some ggplot
  })
})
```

How could I create a link within the text that then redirects to a certain tab. I tried anchor tags but they don't seem to work as the id keeps changing upon each start of the app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stéphane Laurent, who pointed me in the right direction, I managed to create the solution I wanted. In order to keep all the HTML text in the server function I used a combination of `renderUI` and `actionLink`. The solution now looks as follows:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type="tabs",
        id = "tabset", # <- Key element 1
        tabPanel("Contents", htmlOutput("contents")),
        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot"))
      )
    )
  )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$contents <- renderUI({ # <- Key element 2
    list(
      HTML(<p>Some text..</p>),
      actionLink("link", "Link to Plot") # <- Key element 3
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$link, {updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabset", "Plot")}) # <- Key element 4

  output$plot({
    some ggplot
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is possible with a link. But you can use a button and `updateTabsetPanel`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type="tabs",
        id = "tabset",
        tabPanel("Contents", actionButton("go", "Go to plot")),
        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")) 
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabset", "Plot")
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=disp)) + geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Stéphane!! You definitely pointed me in the right direction. Luckily there is an `actionLink` (everyday is a school day). I used this in combiniation with `renderUI` to keep everything in the server function. I'll post my solution soon.